# Member variable initialization with non-default constructor gives error

Tags: c++

> robot.h:11:20: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
>      Queue SQ(10);

```
struct Robot
{
  string m_name; //robot name
  Queue<string> SQ(10); //queue of services
  int m_timer; //time til robot is done
  string m_lastService; //most recent service
};
```

I don't understand why I'm getting an error on this. When I take away the (10) it used the default constructor and works fine. Here is the Queue class.

```
template <typename T>
class Queue : public AbstractQueue<T>
{
  private:
    T* m_array;
    int m_front;
    int m_back;
    int m_capacity;
    int m_size;
  public:
    Queue();
    Queue(int max);
    void setMax(int max);
    bool isEmpty() const;
    const T& front() const throw (Oops);
    const T& back() const throw (Oops);
    void enqueue(const T& x);
    void dequeue();
    void clear();
    ~Queue();
};
```

I used another declaration of the Queue class and it worked in main, but for some reason it won't work in the struct, here is what I declared in main

```
Queue<Robot> R(10);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't specify the non-default constructor used on member variable initialization like this.

You could provide a constructor with [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) to specify the constructor of `Queue` to be used.

```
struct Robot
{
  string m_name; //robot name
  Queue<string> SQ(); //queue of services
  int m_timer; //time til robot is done
  string m_lastService; //most recent service
  Robot() : SQ(10) {}
};
```

Or use [default member initializer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization) (since c++11):

```
Queue<string> SQ{10};
```